# jQuery - unbind and rebind hover on click

Tags: jquery, hover

I want to *unbind* and *rebind* the hover styling when an item is *clicked*.

```
$('.merc-list img').mouseover(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('with-grayscale')){
        $(this).removeClass('with-grayscale');
    }
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.3 + ')');
    $('.merc-list img').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('with-grayscale');
        $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 0.9 + ')');
    });
});

$('.merc-list img').mouseleave(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('with-grayscale')){
        $(this).removeClass('with-grayscale');
    }
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.0 + ')');
    $('.merc-list img').not(this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('with-grayscale')){
            $(this).removeClass('with-grayscale');
        }
        $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.0 + ')');
    });
});

$('.merc-list img').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).bind('mouseover mouseleave'); // rebind for clicked image
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.0 + ')');
        $('.merc-list img').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).bind('mouseover mouseleave'); // rebind for every other image except clicked image
            $(this).removeClass('with-grayscale');
            $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.0 + ')');
        });
    }else{
        $(this).unbind('mouseover mouseleave'); // unbind for clicked image
        if ($(this).hasClass('with-grayscale')){
            $(this).removeClass('with-grayscale');
        }
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 1.3 + ')');
        $('.merc-list img').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).unbind('mouseover mouseleave'); // unbind for every other image except clicked image
            $(this).addClass('with-grayscale');
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + 0.9 + ')');
        });
    }
});
```

So when there is no hover or click event, this is how it originally looks like:
[image: original]

When I hover over it, all the other images shrink and become gray and the element that is hovered over becomes larger and has no grayscale (in this example I'm hovering over Phantom)

[image: focus]

Now when I *click* Phantom, I want to freeze every *mouseover* and *mouseleave* on each of these mercs. **However**, when I *unclick* Phantom, for example, I want to *unfreeze* everything and go back to its original hover animation.

As you can see in my code, I am unbinding and rebinding the *mouseover* and *mouseenter* functionalities, but it's not rebinding (it does not go back to its original hover animations).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding and rebinding, I'd use a `flag`.  A flag is just a boolean that tells your program whether or not to do a certain thing.  So, in this case we will have a flag that will indicate whether or not the mouseenter and mouseleave events should work.

Example:

```js
var shouldHover = true;

$('div').mouseenter(function () {
  if (shouldHover) {
    $(this).css({'background':'#4286f4'})
  }
});

$('div').mouseleave(function () {
  if (shouldHover) {
    $(this).css({'background':'#e3ffad'})
  }
});

$('div').click(function () {
  shouldHover = false;
});
```

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#e3ffad;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: this fixed my problem in a flash. thank you so much neil!! this unbinding and rebinding was giving me a massive headache!